# Mailing List Application?

Tags: email, web-application

Mailing lists are great, but they're a fundamentally different beast than email.  It seems strange to me to keep mailing lists in my email program (Gmail).  Of course I have folders set up to automatically keep them out of my inbox, but if I have hundreds of mailing lists, it gets really out of hand.

**Is there an application (or web application) that is designed specifically as a mailing list "client"?**

Comment: Windows / Linux / Mac ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are already subscribed to hundreds of mailing lists, it is probably too late, but the common sense thing to do would be to use different email accounts.  You could even have one email address redirect email to the other, where it automatically gets sorted.  [Gmail allows you to use aliases](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12096) with the same email account.

Another thing you could do is use RSS Feeds instead, when they are available.  I use Outlook, which includes an RSS reader.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird as email client has the feature of [Saved Search folders](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Saved_Search), that operate as virtual folders. Search folders can be attached anywhere in the real mailbox hierarchy, so can be nicely organized. This lets you leave all your email in one mailbox that is only *virtually* divided into folders.

See this article : [How to Organize Mail Flexibly Using Virtual Folders in Mozilla Thunderbird](http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/Organize_Mail_Flexibly_Using_Virtual_Folders_in_Thunderbird.htm).

To add a similar structure to Gmail, see [Adding Persistent Searches to Gmail](http://blog.persistent.info/2005/03/adding-persistent-searches-to-gmail.html). This uses the [Greasemonkey](http://greasemonkey.mozdev.org/) Firefox extension together with [this user script](http://persistent.info/greasemonkey/gmail.user.js). It adds a "Searches" box on the left side, below the "Labels" and "Invite a friend" ones, where clicking on a search executes the saved query. However, this is not as flexible a solution as when using Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an RSS reader. We've gotten away from newsgroups and newsgroup readers, which were probably more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Are you looking for something that is more forum-like? Or something that groups threaded conversations? Depending on the RSS reader you choose, being able to filter the feeds by source should enable to you see something like threading. But the threading in the gmail interface is better than threading in any RSS, as RSS is more for static articles than for conversation threads. But then you're back to an email client.